# Get the Values from the cells (ListView & ListViewItems)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, cell, listviewitem

I have a ListView. My main goal is to be able, to copy the ListViewItems to the Clipboard and then to Excel. But I have troubles to read the ListView Cells.

To get the Columns I use:

```
var columnNames = new StringBuilder();

foreach (GridViewColumn column in ((GridView)(listViewSolution.View)).Columns)
{
       columnNames.Append(column.Header + "\t");
}
```

Now I want to add the rows, but I'm only able to access the first Cell in the first column, not the second or third..:

```
var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < listViewSolution.Items.Count; i++)
{
    stringBuilder.Append("\n");
    //foreach (GridViewColumn column in ((GridView)(listViewSolution.View)).Columns)
    //{
        //if (column.Header != null)
        //{
            ListViewItem myListBoxItem =
                (ListViewItem)(listViewSolution.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0)); //= Index 0 -> First Row, First Cell; Index 1 = Second Row, First Cell; But do we get: Second Column, First Row????
            stringBuilder.Append(myListBoxItem.Content.ToString() + "\t");
        //}
    //}
}
System.Windows.Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, columnNames.ToString() + stringBuilder.ToString());
```

Help would be much appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

You're not changing the index in the .ContainerFromIndex call each iteration. Use your loop variable there and see what you get.

Comment: Of course I tried that already.. Take a Look at the Comment behind the: `.ContainerFromIndex` , with the next index (1), I'm switching to the next row, but not to the next cell in the first row, I need to get all data from the first row first and then I can increase the index for the next row..